# How to listen for clicks on dynamically generated buttons in TableCell?

Tags: java, button, events, javafx, actionlistener

I have a class Task that takes field values from the database and is displayed as a row in the table.

```
package com.example.javafxapp.models;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class Task {
    private String id;
    private String task;
    private Button done;
    private Button cancel;
    private Button remove;
    private HBox edit;


    public Task(String id, String task, HBox edit, Button done, Button cancel, Button remove) {
        this.id = id;
        this.task = task;
        this.edit = edit;
        this.done = done;
        this.cancel = cancel;
        this.remove = remove;

        edit.getChildren().addAll(done, cancel, remove);
        edit.setSpacing(5);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }
    public HBox getEdit() {
        return edit;
    }

    public void setEdit(HBox edit) {
        this.edit = edit;
    }

    public Button getDone() {
        return done;
    }

    public void setDone(Button done) {
        this.done = done;
    }

    public Button getCancel() {
        return cancel;
    }

    public void setCancel(Button cancel) {
        this.cancel = cancel;
    }

    public Button getRemove() {
        return remove;
    }

    public void setRemove(Button remove) {
        this.remove = remove;
    }
}
```

There is a controller that fills the rows of the table with objects of the Task class.

```
package com.example.javafxapp.controllers;

import com.example.javafxapp.models.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.javafxapp.models.Task;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class AppController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane appPane;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Task> currentTable;

    @FXML
    private Tab currentTab;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane currentTabAnchorPane;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, String> currentIdColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, String> currentTasksColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, HBox> editColumn;


    ObservableList<Task> currentTasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        getAllTasks();
        initCols();

        //Вutton mouse click listener from Tableview cells.

    }

    private void initCols(){
        currentIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Task, String>("id"));
        currentTasksColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Task, String>("task"));
        editColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Task, HBox>("edit"));

        currentTable.getItems().clear();
        currentTable.setItems(currentTasks);
    }

    private void getAllTasks() {
        ResultSet rs = new DatabaseHandler().getTaskTableFromDb();
            try {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    if(rs.getString("state").equals("current")) {
                        currentTasks.add(new Task(rs.getString("idtask"),
                                rs.getString("task"),
                                rs.getString("state"),
                                new HBox(),
                                new Button("done"),
                                new Button("cancel"),
                                new Button("remove")));
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

I need to listen for clicks on buttons in cells.
But those buttons are not present as fields in the controller. How can I do this without referring to a specific cell?

Comment: Your model class `Task` should not have UI elements (buttons) in it. It should store data only. Use a custom cell factory to generate cells that display the buttons.

Comment: this feels like a repost - is it? If so, don't don't don't. Anyway: [mcve] please.. mind the __M__! and don't use names for your custom classes that are already used by the framework

Comment: @James_D Important note. Thank you. I removed the elements from the model, created them in the controller, but now I can’t associate a specific button with a specific model object.

Comment: @kleopatra This is part of my project, not a repost. I tried to remove everything superfluous from it, but, apparently, not enough. As for the class name, I understood, thanks.

Comment: Depending on how you set things up, you can call `getItem()` or `getIndex()` in the cell to get the model object. Post a [mre].

Comment: @James_D I try but:
1. my buttons don't have ID, they are generated automatically in filled rows.
2. and nothing can be obtained from the event (MOUSE_CLICK), except for the button itself, mouse buttons and the coordinates.
Thus, I again cannot get a connection between buttons and model objects (or at least specific lines).
Seems I don't understand something very important about events.

Comment: None of that prevents you calling methods in the cell. Again, create a [mre] and post it in the question

Comment: please read the referenced help page, make sure you understand it and act accordingly in your next question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model class `Task` should not have any Ui components in it. It should look something like

```
public class Task {
    private String id;
    private String task;


    public Task(String id, String task) {
        this.id = id;
        this.task = task;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }
}
```

You should strongly consider implementing the model class with [JavaFX Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) instead of implementing it as a plain Java bean.

To display UI controls in cells in the table, you should implement a custom `TableCell` and generate instances of it in a cell factory. Probably the most convenient approach is to let the column containing those cells have the entire model as its value. That way the cell's `getItem()` method will return the model for its specific row.

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Task, Task> editColumn ;

@FXML
private void initialize() {

    // ...

    editColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue()));
    editColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TaskActionCell());

    // ...
}
```

And the cell implementation (here this is an inner class in the controller) looks like

```
public class TaskActionCell extends TableCell<Task, Task> {

    private final HBox graphic;

    public TaskActionCell() {
        Button done = new Button("Done");
        Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        Button remove = new Button("Remove");
        graphic = new HBox(5, done, cancel remove);

        remove.setOnAction(event -> {
            Task task = getItem();
            currentTasks.remove(task);
        });

        // other event handlers are similar

    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Task task, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(task, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setGraphic(graphic);
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to just let the cell values be null (e.g. using `TableColumn<Task, Void> editColumn`, etc.), and to access the row value in the cell with `getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex())`, but that seems less elegant.

---

Here is a complete working example, using the `Task` class I defined above.

### `Table.fxml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.actiontable.TableController">
    <center>
    <TableView fx:id="table">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn text="Id" fx:id="idColumn"/>
            <TableColumn text="Task" fx:id="taskColumn"/>
            <TableColumn text="Edit" fx:id="editColumn"/>
        </columns>
    </TableView>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

### `TableController.java`

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TableController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Task> table ;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, Task> editColumn ;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, String> idColumn ;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Task, String> taskColumn ;

    private ObservableList<Task> currentTasks ;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getId()));
        taskColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getTask()));

        editColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue()));
        editColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TaskActionCell());

        currentTasks = loadTasks();

        table.setItems(currentTasks);
    }

    private ObservableList<Task> loadTasks() {
        List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 20; i++) {
            tasks.add(new Task(Integer.toString(i), "Task "+i));
        }
        return FXCollections.observableList(tasks);
    }

    public class TaskActionCell extends TableCell<Task, Task> {

        private final HBox graphic;

        public TaskActionCell() {
            Button done = new Button("Done");
            Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
            Button remove = new Button("Remove");
            graphic = new HBox(5, done, cancel, remove);

            remove.setOnAction(event -> {
                Task task = getItem();
                currentTasks.remove(task);
            });

            // other event handlers are similar

        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Task task, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(task, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setGraphic(graphic);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Application class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("Table.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Application running:

[image]

After pressing lots of "Remove" buttons:

[image]

Comment: Thank for that, but:
1. It requires to make controller field currentTasks static or to make class TaskActionCell -non-static.
2. new SimpleObjectProperty<>  - brackets underlined in red.
3. editColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TaskActionCell());   - all after "new" is underlined in red too.

Comment: @filippkos Updated. In future, please provide a [mre].

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally everything worked. I tried to solve this problem for 3 weeks until I submitted a case here. In the future I will try to give as abstract examples as possible.

Comment: There was another question. Is it possible to get an instance of task corresponding to a specific line in the constructor of class TaskActionCell, but without a listener? If, for example, I just need to display some field (text) of the model, but I haven't action.

Comment: @filippkos No. The cell won’t be displaying a `Task` at the time it is constructed. And the `Task` may change at any given time anyway. It sounds like you need to review how all this works.